# Похожий на неизвестное вещество

Tags: синтаксис, семантика

***[Присутствующих] осыпали порошком, похожим на неизвестное вещество.***

Похоже на перл "из протокола". Но это дикторская речь.

Внимание, вопрос.
1. Что хотел сказать диктор или автор текста?
2. Если это нечто осмысленное, то как надо по-русски?

Ответ на второй вопрос без ответа на первый не принимается.

Comment: Не очень думающий человек произнес бессмыслицу. Так сказать нельзя.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Не похожим ни на одно известное вещество**.
2. **Неизвестным порошком**. И да — может, *осыпали*, а не обсыпали? Или можно и так? Осыпают обычно наградами или милостями... В общем, не знаю.

Comment: Про о(б)сыпали не думал. Вот сейчас послушал - да, **осыпали**. Спасибо, поправлю точности ради. Хотя, думаю, обсыпанный здесь не [грамматическая] ошибка. По сути вопроса и ответа - пока не решил. Подумаю.

Answer (score 2):

1. Диктор хотел сказать, что химический состав вещества, высыпанного на людей в виде порошка, ещё не удалось выявить. Вряд ли к каждому подходили и обсыпали его с ног до головы или распыляли порошок из шланга; скорее всего, его высыпали сверху.
   Что могло побудить так выразиться? Официальный отчёт, в котором всячески избегают определённостей до окончания следствия: не золото, а "желтый металл", не прокурор N недостойно выглядел в распространённом видео, а "человек похожий на прокурора N"; здесь попытка выразиться в таком же ключе привела к бессмыслице (нельзя говорить о "похожести" на неизвестно как выглядящее и т.п.).
2. На посетителей был высыпан порошок неизвестного химического состава.

Answer (score 2):

1) Это фестиваль красок, когда осыпают друг друга цветными порошками.

2) Присутствующих осыпали порошком неизвестного происхождения.

Comment: 1. Нет, это о ЧП на Тайване. Порошок потом загорелся. Не надо фантазировать. Смысл фразы, пожалуйста, "похожий.на неизвестное"

Answer (score 0):

Хотел сказать "обсыпали порошком, похожим на известное вещество", но перемудрил.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку мне придется на какое-то время отдохнуть от ресурса, даю свой вариант.

1. Слово "неизвестный" на милицейском жаргоне означает "неустановленный", очевидно (для меня), что здесь именно такой смысл. "Похожий" тогда означает недостаточную уверенность в том что вещество действительно не установлено или не будет установлено в обозримое время.
2. Не знаю. Хотел услышать ответ - не услышал.